# Clamping the results of 1-(x/y) to -1 .. +1 range for positive inputs, and special casing zero

Tags: assembly, x87

I have two problems to solve in x87 ASM and I'm a little confused by it, could anyone suggest some ideas?

Equation: 1-(x/y)

Background: X and Y are always positive floating point numbers, but the result of the calculation can be either positive or negative. This is part of a wider calculation which always results in a positive number.

Problem 1: Either X or Y can be zero (and both can be zero simultaneously). Divide by zero is bad. However if either value is zero, I want the final result to be "1" (i.e. Fld1, pop any unnecessary numbers and then move on)

Problem 2: The result must always fall between -1 and +1. If the result is above 1 or below -1, I just want to replace the result with 1. (I.e. In the case of 1-(35/0.01).)

So far I have the following:

```
fld dword [y] ; Check if either number is 0
fmul dword [x] ; 
Fldz
fcomip st(1),st(0)
je exit_1  ; If result is zero jump outta here 
fld dword [y] ; Otherwise load the floats
fld dword [x]
fdivp        ; Do X/Y
fld1        
fsubrp       ; 1 - X/Y
????? ; Need some code here to check result is between -1 and 1. If not, replace the result with "1" every time. 

.exit_1
fld1 ; Use 1 as the result for the next calculation 
jump to_next_calc
```

Comment: You have a comment saying "multiplying together" but aren't actually multiplying anything. And I think `fcomp st(0)` will compare a number with itself.

Comment: @interjay Sorry typing on my phone. Missed a step - edited. Just need to know if X×Y is zero, which means one of the two definitely is.

Comment: You can get x*y=0 when |x|>0 and |y|>0 but both are small enough. I would calculate x/y and check result for infinity and uncertainty.

Comment: @dimich What code do I need for that? Have never needed to deal with infinity before

Comment: @X87-Learner After `fdiv` run `fxam`, store status register to `ax`: `fstsw ax`. Select flags C3, C2, C0 by ANDing `ah` with 45h. Value 5 in `ah` will indicate infinity, value 1 will indicate NaN.

Comment: Cross-posted [from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Assembly_language/comments/193uyji/help_with_1xy_equation/).

Comment: Your `fcomp` won't work as expected.  Use `fcomip` instead.  Also note that the zero flag indicates equality for comparisons.  If you want to find if a number is zero, compare with zero.

Comment: @dimich I'll give it a try, though the If x>=y+y solution provided has worked really well

Comment: @fuv I just revised my original post (first four lines). Any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to the value of `1 - x/y` to go below -1, `x/y > 2`, meaning that you can early exit with

```
   if (x >= (y + y)) return -1.0f;
```

Having `=` also handles the case of `x==0 and y==0`, where as the `>` handles the case of `x>0 and y==0`.

Then proceed normally and the output is limited to `[-1 .. 1]` automatically.

The multiplication of `y` by two can be theoretically speeded up by adding 1 to the exponent - given that the number is not denormal, inf, or nan, and does not overflow...

Comment: *The multiplication of y by two can be theoretically speeded up by adding 1 to the exponent* - not with x87.  The extra load/store to do integer addition on an FP bit-pattern would be slower than `fadd`.  And `fscale` has never been particularly fast compared to `fmul` on CPUs from this century, despite the docs still saying it "provides rapid multiplication or division by integral powers of 2" (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fscale).

Comment: According to Agner Fog's measurements, `fscale` worst case is Skylake, 27 uops with 130 cycle throughput, vs. fadd and fmul at 3 and 5c latency and 1c throughput.  Even P5 Pentium (without SSE) took 20-32 cycles vs. 3c fully pipelined fadd/fmul.  Nehalem and Ice Lake take 11 cycles, so it seems somewhere in mid Sandybridge-family the microcode for it got super bad. Or data-dependent and Agner didn't always test as much?  Haswell at 25-75 uops, and 49-125c latency, throughput not reported. For SKX he reports 11c throughput and latency, same as the next line.  Could be a testing or editing error

Comment: Anyway, x87 does have an instruction to adjust exponents, but it's not fast anywhere.  Even the lower end of Agner Fog's measurements for AMD CPUs and Intel CPUs where it's faster weren't fast.  (https://agner.org/optimize/).  I guess for x86-64, you could do an integer `add` and compare bit-patterns as integers, since they're both positive that works.  But you need FP division.

Comment: @PeterCordes Assuming a super-scalar FPU, it might be faster to first compute the reciprocal of `y` while the other checks are happening.  Then at the end divide.  This could yield better performance, but might also perform worse.

Comment: @fuz: The other checks don't change the value of `x`, and the OP hasn't mentioned using the same `y` with multiple `x` values, so if you're going to start a slow computation before the branching, you'd do the full `x/y`.  `1/y` typically costs as much as `x/y`, and needs a multiply later.  Except that x87, unlike SSE, was and is slower for at least NaN, maybe also Inf outputs.  Is that the point of your recip suggestion?

Comment: @fuz:  With pipelined execution that allows the fadd/fcomi chain to start in the cycle after starting fdiv, yeah that could reduce critical-path latency.  (Especially if we're worried about an out-of-order exec CPU mispredicting a branch and not starting the division until after fcomi/jcc.)  But if divider throughput is a bottleneck (like if doing this for many x/y pairs in a tightish loop), it means we always start a division even for cases where we won't use the result.

Comment: @PeterCordes You raise good points and I think doing the division directly might indeed be better here.

Comment: This solution was really elegant, I tested it and it seems to work! This is just one part of a much longer equation and it saves codespace to just do a quick fld y / fadd y / jge x style comp.